# Is there a plugin for ios cloudkit interface

Tags: ios, nativescript, cloudkit

On ios, I'd like to store some data specific to the logged in apple-id. Some text key-value pairs.

Is there a nativescript plugin that'll help me do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we have a plugin for Cloud Kit, you might want to write one.

Answer (score 0):

Dashman,

No plugin, but cloudKit JS comes to mind. Watch this WWDC from 2015.

WWDC https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/710/
Apple docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkitjs
Tutorial https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios9-day-by-day-day13-cloudkit-web-services/